# VBA ErrorHandling, return line of code that caused error

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

If I have the following code,

```
x = 4
y = x / 0
```

Err.Description will return "Division by zero" but is there a way to return "y = x / 0"?

Comment: There is no way to show the user the line of code that causes the error. They would need to click debug to find that out when the error occurs.

Comment: In VB6 there used to be an undocumented feature called Error Line: `Erl`

Comment: Use `On Error GoTo` statements to define an error-handling subroutine (/line label), and have a `Stop`, then `Resume` statement in there; if it breaks there, following execution (F8) takes you to the error-throwing statement. But that won't give you a document line number, no.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a string variable and before every line of code, you push `VBProject.VBComponents("Module1").CodeModule.Lines(...)` into the variable. Then, when the error occurs, you have the exact line of code that caused the error stored in the variable!

Throw in a custom error handler and you can msgbox it right to the user's screen!

```vb
Sub test()
    Dim ErrLine As String
    On Error GoTo ErrHand
    Dim x As Long, y As Long
    ErrLine = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("Module1").CodeModule.Lines(6, 1)
    x = 4
    ErrLine = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("Module1").CodeModule.Lines(8, 1)
    y = x / 0
    Exit Sub
ErrHand:
    MsgBox ErrLine 'Shows "y = x / 0"
End Sub
```

This is of course, very tedious and prone to error. It depends on constants for `LineStart` in the `Lines` property and if the code is updated or changed, the line numbers may shift and break the whole thing, meaning hundreds of these constants might need to be updated.

And it is mostly pointless, since the user can press Debug in the default error messagebox and it will open the VBProject and bring them right to the line that caused the error.

So yes, it is possible, but it has more cons than pros.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say what version of VBA you are using, so here's what I use in Access 2010 VBA (Office 2010). It probably works for Access 2007 VBA, and above (any .accdb extension).

This post includes the following functions:

**SearchModule** - Search a VBA module for the specified text and return the line found. Useful for finding numbered lines and returning the text of the line.

**ErrorMsgBox** - Display a preformatted error message in an ErrorHandler routine that can look up the actual line from the module/procedure specified. All that's needed is to pass the Err object, Erl, and module name, and it does the rest. All other arguments are optional. Actually, ALL arguments are optional, but you get a lesser message. Requires SearchModule().

**MyFunction** - A function showing how SearchModule() can be used. Requires SearchModule().

**MyFunction2** - A function showing how ErrorMsgBox() can be used. It's a modified version of MyFunction(). Requires SearchModule() and ErrorMsgBox().

**Copy/Paste the following code into a module called modModuleFunctions**, and it should run as expected (in Access 2010, at least).

Scroll down and do the same for the test functions.

**IMPORTANT: See note at the very end of this post about an MSAccess bug discovered.**

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

' Set this to the name of the module that contains this code.
Const MOD_NAME = "modModuleFunctions"    

Function SearchModule( _
         sModName As String, _
         Optional sProcName As String = "", _
         Optional sSearchText As String = "", _
         Optional sProcType As String = "", _
         Optional bStripLineNumbers As Boolean = True, _
         Optional bStripComments As Boolean = True, _
         Optional bQuiet As Boolean = False _
    ) As Variant

    ' Purpose:
    '   Search sProcName procedure in sModName module
    '   for sSearchText and return the line of text found.
    '   Line numbers and comments may be stripped.
    '
    ' Arguments:
    '   sModName          - The name of the module to be searched.
    '                       Required.
    '
    '   sProcName         - The name of the procedure to be searched.
    '                       If not specified, then the entire module is searched,
    '                       and SearchModule() sets this argument to the procedure 
    '                       containing the text found.
    '                       Optional.
    '
    '   sSearchText       - The text to be searched for. Returns Null if not specified.
    '                       Optional (sort of). (See Note 5)
    '
    '   sProcType         - The type of procedure found.
    '                       Pass an empty string variable, and SearchModule()
    '                       will set it to the type of procedure that contains
    '                       the text that was found. 
    '                       Pass a string into sProcType, and SearchModule() 
    '                       leaves it unchanged.
    '                       Optional.
    '
    '   bStripLineNumbers - Do not return line numbers in the returned text.
    '                       Ignored if lines do not start with
    '                       a numeric value followed by a space.
    '                       Optional. Default = True.
    '
    '   bStripComments    - Strips any comments from the end of the line.
    '                       Optional. Default = True.
    '
    '   bQuiet            - Suppresses error messages from this function.
    '                       Optional. Default = False.
    '
    ' Returns:
    '    1. The line of text found, modified by 2 optional arguments.
    '    2. Returns Null if sSearchText is NOT specified,
    '       an error occurs, or the text was not found.
    '
    ' Notes:
    '    1. If you are expecting to find unique line numbers,
    '       as reported by Erl (error line function), you must
    '       manually insert unique numbers followed by a space,
    '       at the beginning of the appropriate line(s).
    '
    '    2. Not all lines need to be numbered, only the ones
    '       that may be trouble spots). No need to number lines
    '       that cannot fail.
    '
    '       IMPORTANT: If a line that fails is not numbered, and
    '       others before it are, VBA sets Erl to the last line number
    '       read before the failed line, giving you the wrong error line.
    '       Be sure to number ALL lines that are potential trouble spots,
    '       else you'll have even MORE trouble debugging your code.
    '
    '    3. Make sure the line numbers used appear nowhere else
    '       in your code, or else you may receive unexpected matches.
    '
    '    4. Any integers may be used. 
    '       Line numbers should be in ascending order,
    '       else, Erl may not return the right line.
    '       Often it DOES return the right line number, 
    '       even if out of order, but NOT always.
    '
    '    5. The Module.Find method (used by this, the SearchModule()
    '       function) requires the sSearchText argument to be specified.
    '       So if sSearchText argument is not specified, Module.Find
    '       would fail. Thus, it is required, but defined as Optional
    '       in the arguments to this function.

    On Error GoTo SearchModule_ERROR

    Dim mMod As Module

    Dim lStartLine As Long, lEndLine As Long
    Dim lStartCol As Long, lEndCol As Long

    Dim sLineFound As String
    Dim vTmp As Variant

    DoCmd.OpenModule sModName
    Set mMod = Modules(sModName)

    If sProcName = "" Then
       lStartLine = 1
       lEndLine = mMod.CountOfLines - mMod.CountOfDeclarationLines
    Else
       lStartLine = mMod.ProcBodyLine(sProcName, vbext_pk_Proc)
       lEndLine = lStartLine + mMod.ProcCountLines(sProcName, vbext_pk_Proc)
    End If

    SearchModule = Null                            ' Failure or not found returns Null.
    If mMod.Find(sSearchText, lStartLine, lStartCol, lEndLine, lEndCol) Then
       sLineFound = mMod.Lines(lStartLine, lEndLine - lStartLine + 1)
       If sProcType = "" Then                      ' Extract the type of procedure.
          sProcName = mMod.ProcOfLine(lStartLine, vbext_pk_Proc)
          lStartLine = mMod.ProcBodyLine(sProcName, vbext_pk_Proc)
          sProcType = mMod.Lines(lStartLine, 1)
          sProcType = Split(sProcType, "(", 2)(0)  ' Remove arguments from declaration.
          sProcType = "(" & Left(sProcType, InStrRev(sProcType, " ") - 1) & ")" ' Get type.
       End If
       If bStripLineNumbers Then
          vTmp = Split(sLineFound, " ", 2)
          If IsNumeric(vTmp(0)) Then sLineFound = Trim(vTmp(1))
       End If
       If bStripComments Then sLineFound = Trim(Split(sLineFound, "'")(0))
       SearchModule = Trim(sLineFound)
    End If

SearchModule_EXIT:

    Exit Function

SearchModule_ERROR:

    If Not bQuiet Then
       MsgBox "Error " & Err & " occurred in SearchModule function." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
              Error, vbExclamation, "SearchModule() Error"
    End If

    Resume SearchModule_EXIT

End Function

Function ErrorMsgBox( _
         Optional sAdditionalMessage As String = "", _
         Optional oErr As ErrObject = Nothing, _
         Optional ByVal sErrLine As String = "0", _
         Optional ByVal sModName As String = "", _
         Optional ByVal sProcName As String = "", _
         Optional ByVal vbButtonsAndIcon As VbMsgBoxStyle = vbExclamation, _
         Optional sTitle As String = "Error occurred", _
         Optional bStripLineNumbers As Boolean = True, _
         Optional bStripComments As Boolean = True, _
         Optional bQuiet As Boolean = False _
    ) As Integer

    Const CR2 = vbCrLf & vbCrLf   ' Double up the line feeds.

    Dim sErrDescr As String
    Dim sErrNum As String
    Dim vErrorLine As Variant
    Dim sMsg As String        
    Dim sProcType As String  ' The type of procedure to be displayed in the message.

    ' Purpose:
    '
    '   Display a preformatted error message in an ErrorHandler routine,
    '   that looks up the actual line from the module/procedure specified.
    '
    ' Arguments:
    '
    '   sAdditionalMessage - An additional message to be appended to the 
    '                        auto-generated message.
    '                        Optional. Default = ""
    '
    '   oErr               - The Err object. Just pass Err to this argument 
    '                        from any code.
    '                        Optional. Default = Nothing
    '
    '   sErrLine           - The error line. Just pass Erl to this argument 
    '                        from any code.
    '                        Optional. This is only needed if you want to extract 
    '                                  a line from a module. If so, you must also 
    '                                  include at least the sModName argument.
    '                        Default = "0"
    '
    '   sModName           - The name of the module to be searched for the line 
    '                        that failed (sErrLine).
    '                        Optional, unless sProcName is specified, which is 
    '                        contained in sModName.
    '                        Default = ""
    '
    '   sProcName          - The name of the procedure to be searched for the line 
    '                        that failed (sErrLine). If not specified, then sModName 
    '                        module is searched.
    '                        Optional. Default = ""
    '
    '   vbButtonsAndIcon   - This controls the buttons, icons and return value.
    '                        Optional. Default = vbExclamation (See Returns, below).
    '
    '   sTitle             - The title you want to display in the MsgBox.
    '                        Optional. Default = "", which sets MsgBox's efault title.
    '
    '   bStripLineNumbers  - Do not return line numbers in the text returned 
    '                        by SearchModule(). Ignored if lines do not start 
    '                        with a numeric value followed by a space.
    '                        Optional. Default = True.
    '
    '   bStripComments     - Strips any comments from the line returned by SearchModule().
    '                        Optional. Default = True.
    '
    '   bQuiet             - Suppresses error messages from the SearchModule function.
    '                        Optional. Default = False.
    '
    ' Returns:
    '
    '    The same values as the MsgBox function, which depend on the 
    '       vbButtonsAndIcon argument.
    '    See help on the MsgBox function for valid vbMsgBoxStyle values 
    '       and how they relate to the buttons and icons displayed, 
    '       and possible return values.
    '
    ' Notes:
    '
    '    If sModName is specified, but not sProcName, then line numbers 
    '       in the entire module must be unique for valid lines to be found.
    '       The SearchModule() function is used to find these lines, 
    '       so line numbers must not also be used for any constants in 
    '       the module, or they may match, erroneously.
    '       See SearchModule() function, for more information.

    If Not oErr Is Nothing Then
       sErrNum = oErr.Number
       sErrDescr = oErr.Description
    End If

    ' The same string variables passed as ByVal arguments are used to build the message.
    If sErrNum = "0" Then 
       sErrNum = "Error occurred" 
    Else 
       sErrNum = "Error " & sErrNum & " occurred"
    End If

    ' Reset errors so we can trap errors from SearchModule() function.
    On Error Resume Next  

    If sErrLine = "0" Then ' Error line number is not available.
       sErrLine = "."
    Else                   ' Error line number is available.
       If sModName = "" Then
          vErrorLine = ""
       Else                ' Module name is available, so extract line from module.
          vErrorLine = SearchModule(sModName, sProcName, sErrLine, sProcType, _
                       bStripLineNumbers, bStripComments, bQuiet)
       End If
       If IsNull(vErrorLine) Then          ' SearchModule() failed.
          vErrorLine = "Line that caused the error:" & vbCrLf & _
                       "(Couldn't extract text from " & sModName & " module)" & CR2
       Else
          If vErrorLine <> "" Then vErrorLine = "Line that caused the error:" & CR2 & _
             vErrorLine & CR2
       End If
       sErrLine = " (line # " & sErrLine & ")"
    End If

    sErrLine = sErrLine & CR2
    If sProcName <> "" Then sProcName = " in " & Trim(sProcName & " " & sProcType)
    If sErrDescr <> "" Then sErrDescr = sErrDescr & CR2

    sMsg = sErrNum & sProcName & sErrLine & sErrDescr & vErrorLine & sAdditionalMessage

    ErrorMsgBox = MsgBox(sMsg, vbButtonsAndIcon, sTitle)

End Function
```

**Copy/Paste the following code into a module called modMyFunctionTest**.

Once you copied/pasted all four functions into their respective modules, Open the Immediate window (CTRL+G in the Access VBA editor) and type:
`? MyFunction()`
or
`? MyFunction2()`
and press enter and you should get explanatory 'divide by zero' errors from the two test function versions.

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

' Set this to the name of the module that contains this code.
Const MOD_NAME = "modMyFunctionTest"

Function MyFunction() As Variant

    ' Example of how to use SearchModule() function.
    ' Returns Null if an error occurred.
    
    Const FUNC_NAME = "MyFunction"

    On Error GoTo MyFunction_ERROR
    
    Dim A As Long
    Dim B As Long
    Dim C As Long
    
    ' An error will be generated by this code.
    ' Note: Line numbers should (must?) be in ascending order.
    ' Else, Erl doesn't always return the right line.
    ' Often it does return the right line number, even if out of order.
    ' They DO have to be unique per procedure.
100 A = 1
200 B = 0
300 C = A / B    ' This line will cause an error.
400 C = Int("B") ' This line will cause a different error if it passes the above.
                 ' Set B = 1 in line 200 to see second error message.
  
999 MyFunction = C
     
MyFunction_EXIT:

    Exit Function
    
MyFunction_ERROR:

    Dim sMsg As String
    
    If Erl Then  ' Error line is available.
       sMsg = "Error " & Err & " occurred in " & FUNC_NAME & _
              " function (line # " & Erl & ")." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
              Error & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
              "Error was caused by the following line:" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
              "With line number/comments: " & vbCrLf & _
                 SearchModule(MOD_NAME, FUNC_NAME, Erl, , False, False, True) _
                 & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
              "No line number: " & vbCrLf & _
                 SearchModule(MOD_NAME, FUNC_NAME, Erl, , True, False, False) _
                 & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
              "No comments: " & vbCrLf & _
                 SearchModule(MOD_NAME, FUNC_NAME, Erl, , False, True, False) _
                 & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
              "No line number/comments: " & vbCrLf & _
                 SearchModule(MOD_NAME, FUNC_NAME, Erl, , True, True, False)
    Else   ' No Error line is available.
       sMsg = "Error " & Err & " occurred in " & FUNC_NAME & _
              " function." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & Error
    End If

    MsgBox sMsg, vbExclamation, FUNC_NAME & " error"
   
    MyFunction = Null
   
    Resume MyFunction_EXIT
    
End Function

Function MyFunction2() As Variant

    ' Example of how to use ErrorMsgBox() function to display an error message.
    ' Requires ErrorMsgBox() and SearchModule() functions.
    
    Const FUNC_NAME = "MyFunction2"

    On Error GoTo MyFunction2_ERROR
    
    Dim A As Long
    Dim B As Long
    Dim C As Long
    
    ' An error will be generated by this code.
    ' Note: Line numbers should (must?) be in ascending order.
    ' Else, Erl doesn't always return the right line.
    ' Often it does return the right line number, even if out of order.
    ' They DO have to be unique per procedure.
100 A = 1
200 B = 0
300 C = A / B    ' This line will cause an error.
400 C = Int("B") ' This line will cause a different error if it passes the above.
                 ' Set B = 1 in line 200 to see second error message.
  
999 MyFunction2 = C
     
MyFunction2_EXIT:

    Exit Function
    
MyFunction2_ERROR:
    
    MyFunction2 = ErrorMsgBox("Let's display an additional message.", _
        Err, Erl, MOD_NAME, FUNC_NAME, _
        vbExclamation, FUNC_NAME & " error")
       
    Resume MyFunction2_EXIT
    
End Function
```

**IMPORTANT:**
**Unfortunately, I've found a bug I haven't figured out, yet.**

Everything worked perfectly, so I shut down Access and went to bed.
When I got up in the morning, I tested it again, and Erl didn't return a line number (both test functions).
I tested this over and over many times (both functions) and still got no Erl.

If I changed line 200 to "B = 1", then line 400's error message was displayed properly. I got a valid Erl.
When I changed line 200 back to "B = 0", it too worked. I still got a valid Erl. Neither function failed again until I shut down Access and re-started it again.

This was consistent.
It seems that when MS Access starts up a new session, Erl is not set properly.
Currently, I consider this an Access bug.